# How to make a full width table scroll horizontally if needed?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to create a table element that always takes all the width and, if it's width is bigger than its parent width, displays a scrollbar.

Is there anyway to do that with only CSS?

Right now it has a normal size and displays a scrollbar when needed:

```
table {
    border: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The container need a width to know the moment to put the scroll, you must define it.

Comment: Is there anyway to make this without putting the table element inside a container? The `table` is inside the `article` element, and I don't have much control about this...